# Enable javascript source maps in production in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, source-maps

I was wondering if it is possible to have javascript source maps in a production build of create-react-app

I have asked this question on the create-react-app spectrum but no replies https://spectrum.chat/create-react-app/general/sourcemaps-not-working-in-production~2995d466-e080-4d35-8151-bad3e7f8fb98

Example procedure

```
npx create-react-app test
cd test
**modify src/App.js to console.error in the App function and nothing else really, see below**
yarn build
cd build
python -m SimpleHTTPServer //or some static web server for current folder
visit http://localhost:8000, see that all the names are mangled in the stack trace for the console.error
```

Example App.js modification

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function MyFunction() {
  console.error('hello world')
}
function App() {
  MyFunction()
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the stack trace of this console.error in the devtools

```
App.js:6 hello world
i @ main.34a6654b.chunk.js:1
Ki @ 2.d53d57ba.chunk.js:2
vo @ 2.d53d57ba.chunk.js:2
cu @ 2.d53d57ba.chunk.js:2
ou @ 2.d53d57ba.chunk.js:2
Zo @ 2.d53d57ba.chunk.js:2
qo @ 2.d53d57ba.chunk.js:2
Du @ 2.d53d57ba.chunk.js:2
```

This is unreadable. If a user ends up crashing our app, how do we get a proper stack trace from them ?

I see in the devtools console of the production build it does say "Source map detected" so there is a source map. But it just doesn't function?

Using create-react-app 3.4.1 currently

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by searching for answers that use source maps for production builds

I found this answer works well, specifically the one that is in the "Edit:" and uses source-map-js (source-map requires nodejs and fs module) [Get stack trace as a string when using source map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75400967/get-stack-trace-as-a-string-when-using-source-map)

code at time of use

```
import {RawSourceMap, SourceMapConsumer} from 'source-map-js';

const sourceMaps: {[key: string] : RawSourceMap} = {};
async function getSourceMapFromUri(uri: string) {
  if (sourceMaps[uri] != undefined) {
    return sourceMaps[uri];
  }
  const uriQuery = new URL(uri).search;
  const currentScriptContent = await (await fetch(uri)).text();

  let mapUri = RegExp(/\/\/# sourceMappingURL=(.*)/).exec(currentScriptContent)[1];
  mapUri = new URL(mapUri, uri).href + uriQuery;

  const map = await (await fetch(mapUri)).json();

  sourceMaps[uri] = map;

  return map;
}

async function mapStackTrace(stack: string) {
  const stackLines = stack.split('\n');
  const mappedStack = [];

  for (const line of stackLines) {
    const match = RegExp(/(.*)(http:\/\/.*):(\d+):(\d+)/).exec(line);
    if (match == null) {
      mappedStack.push(line);
      continue;
    }

    const uri = match[2];
    const consumer = new SourceMapConsumer(await getSourceMapFromUri(uri));

    const originalPosition = consumer.originalPositionFor({
      line: parseInt(match[3]),
      column: parseInt(match[4]),
    });

    if (originalPosition.source == null || originalPosition.line == null || originalPosition.column == null) {
      mappedStack.push(line);
      continue;
    }

    mappedStack.push(`${originalPosition.source}:${originalPosition.line}:${originalPosition.column + 1}`);
  }

  return mappedStack.join('\n');
}
```